# C# Newtonsoft JSON - Deserializing DataTable with nested object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following JSON which needs to be deserialized.

```json
{
   "$type":"Lib.TableModel, Lib",
   "DataTable":[
      {
         "Column1":"1",
         "Column2":{
            "$type":"Lib.RelationCellValue, Lib",
            "CellName":"C1",
            "FileName":"test1.txt"
         },
         "Column3":{
            "$type":"Lib.RelationCellValue, Lib",
            "CellName":"C2",
            "FileName":"test2.txt"
         }
      }
   ],
   "Name":"table1"
}
```

As the values for `Column2` and `Column3` are objects, Newtonsoft throws an exception

> "Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable: StartObject"

although the object is annotated with type information.

I'm deserializing like this:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};

try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        model = serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);                    
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
}
```

How can I provide a custom type converter for the Newtonsoft `DataTable` converter (or fix the issue)?

Edit: The `TableModel` is just a class with a `DataTable` property.

```
public class TableModel 
{
    private DataTable dataTable;
    public DataTable DataTable
    {
        get => dataTable;
        set
        {
            dataTable = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DataTable");
        }
    }
}
```

The items in the `DataTable` are `RelationCellValues`:

```
 public class RelationCellValue
 {
     public string CellName { get; set; }
     public string FileName { get; set; }
 }
```

Edit2: The number of columns in the DataTable is dynamic. Test code for generating a sample table:

```
 public void LoadData()
        {
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            DataColumn column;

            column = new DataColumn("Column1");
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataColumn("Column2");
            column.DataType = typeof(RelationCellValue);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataColumn("Column3");
            column.DataType = typeof(RelationCellValue);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(column);

            // Header row
            var row = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

            //First row
            row = dataTable.NewRow();
            LoadCellValues(row, 1);
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

            //Second row
            row = dataTable.NewRow();
            LoadCellValues(row, 2);
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

            //Third row
            row = dataTable.NewRow();
            LoadCellValues(row, 3);
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        public void LoadCellValues(DataRow dataRow, int ordinalNumber)
        {
            dataRow[0] = ordinalNumber.ToString();
            dataRow[1] = new RelationCellValue() { CellName = "First Cell", FileName = "test.txt" };
            dataRow[2] = new RelationCellValue() { CellName = "Second Cell", FileName = "test.txt" }; ;
        }
```

Comment: What is your model class structure ?

Comment: @EricaC Can you please share with us the definition of `DataTable` as well?

Comment: Hi, The `DataTable` needs to be flexible (number of columns can vary). I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: As DataTable needs to be flexible, why you need the DataTable class? Just keep it in a JObejct.

Comment: Because the DataTable binds to a WPF DataGrid.